# Quotient topology and the need for continuity

Tags: general-topology

I was going through a lecture note introducing quotient topology.

homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~jsimon/COURSES/M132Fall07/M132Fall07_QuotientSpaces.pdf

On page 4 of this , while introducing quotient topology it says that the passage of X to X*(which is the equivalence class) is desired to be continuous.

I would like to know why should we want this passage to be continuous ? What happens in case of discontinuous passage ?

Comment: continuity is the whole point of topology. Topologies exist so that we can define what it means for functions to be continuous. From the point of view of topology, nothing is more natural than to ask "what is the largest topology on the quotient so that the quotient map is continuous?". What happens if you do not demand continuity? well, then you are not doing topology but something else, and then the answer depends on what is that something else you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Topology isn't just the study of topological spaces - it's really the study of topological spaces and continuous maps between them. Most theorems in topology deal with continuous maps. If the natural map $X\to X^\ast$ isn't required to be continuous, you're not really imposing any topological structure on the map, and you can get pathological behavior (just think of examples from [real] analysis/set theory of set-theoretic functions with terrible [analytic] behavior); what's worse, you can get behavior that can't be effectively studied using the tools topology provides.

Comment: So , to provide scope to the structure named topology to expand , right ?

Comment: The quotient topology on X/E is defined to be the strongest topology  such that the quotient map is continuous. It is a useful tool in topology, which is....see Stahl's answer.